# Reading a matrix of structures skips last member variable of each structure

Tags: c, matrix, struct

I am currently learning how to work with **structures** in **C** and I have encountered the following problem while reading a matrix of structures from input: I have a structure which contains **4 member variables** and I want to read it from input and place the values inside a **two dimensional array**. After I enter the value for the **third** member variable of each structure it **skips the fourth** variable and prompts me to enter a value for the **first** variable of the following structure.

Here is how **the structure** is defined:

```
struct zone{
    char tc[20],or[20]; 
    char dir;
    int nrc; 
};
```

Here is the code that I wrote to read the structures from input:

```
int n, m, i, j;
struct zone **a;

scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            scanf("%s", &a[i][j].or);
            scanf("%s", &a[i][j].tc);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j].nrc);
            scanf("%c", &a[i][j].dir);
        }
    }
```

So, in this particular example, I can't enter a value for the variable **dir** inside each struct (it prompts me to enter a value for the next **or** variable).

Comment: Your last scanf is eating the newline character btw. And don't pass the address of the string, just the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement `scanf("%d", &a[i][j].nrc)` does not reads the newline character from the `ENTER` key.

When you type let's say 10, you type a `1`, a `0` and then the `ENTER` key. So there are now three characters in the input buffer. `scanf("%d")` reads the `1` and the `0`, interpreting them as the number `10`, but the newline character is still in the input buffer. The `scanf("%d")` will immediately read this newline character, and the program will then go on to the next scanf, and wait for you to enter a string.

**EDIT**: Solution could be use `scanf(" %c", &a[i][j].dir);` add space before `%c` format specifier

Comment: That does not solve the problem with the last scanf.

Comment: @2501 Edited, newline character of last scanf need to be removed.